# Python Pillow: Make image progressive before sending to 3rd party server

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library

I have an image that I am uploading using Django Forms, and its available in the variable as `InMemoryFile` What I want to do is to make it progressive.

### Code to make an image a progressive

```
img = Image.open(source)
img.save(destination, "JPEG", quality=80, optimize=True, progressive=True)
```

### Forms.py

```
my_file = pic.pic_url.file
photo = uploader.upload_picture_to_album(title=title, file_obj=my_file)
```

The issue is, I have to save the file in case I want to make it progressive, and open it again to send it to the server. (It seems a redundant actions to make it progressive)

I just want to know if there is anyway to make an image progressive which does not save the image physically on disk but in memory, which I can use the existing code to upload it?

### Idea

Looking for something similar.

```
    my_file=pic.pic_url.file
    progressive_file = (my_file)
    photo = picasa_api.upload_picture_to_album(title=title, file_obj=progressive_file)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want is not saving the intermediate file to disk, you can save it to a `StringIO`. Both `PIL.open()` and `PIL.save()` accept *file-like* objects as well as filenames.

```
img = Image.open(source)
progressive_img = StringIO()
img.save(progressive_img, "JPEG", quality=80, optimize=True, progressive=True)
photo = uploader.upload_picture_to_album(title=title, file_obj=progressive_img)
```

The uploader needs to support working with the `StringIO` but that is hopefully the case.

It's probably possible to directly stream the result from `save()` using suitable coroutines, but that is a little more work.

Comment: Saved my day; Thanks +1

Comment: Is jpeg format only gives the progressive images why not png format images? I have a doubt like I have seen all the blogs are talking about progressive jpegs only and not about any png format images. can someone clarify?

Comment: @siluverukirankumar That does not quite have anything do to with the original question, but nonetheless: With PNG, progressive en-/decoding is achieved using [Interlacing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#Interlacing)